# Download Shiny Survey Results to CSV

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I made a simple survey using shiny that takes some user inputs. I would like to download the survey results as a csv file. Here's what I have currently:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI for survey
ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Pet Survey"),

# Sidebar with a selector and checkboxes 
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
     selectInput("type",
                 "Type:",
                 c("Cat" = 1,
                   "Dog" = 2)
                ),

     checkboxGroupInput(inputId="size",
                        label = "Size",
                        choices = list("Small" = "small",
                                    "Medium" = "medium",
                                    "Large" = "large"),
                        selected = NULL)
                        ),
     mainPanel(
               HTML("Download data"),
               br(), br(), 
               downloadButton("download_data", "Download data")
              )
     )



# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

# Download file
output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
filename = ("response.csv"),
content = function(file) { 
write_csv(response %>% select(input$selected_var), path = file) 
}
)

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run and click on the download button, it saved as a txt file with nothing in it. I'm just not sure how the user input data is structured. Essentially I would like to get a table that looks like this:

```
Dog, Cat, Small, Medium, Large
1, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

And this means a user selected Dog and checked box for Medium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working `server` function

```
# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Download file
  output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
    filename = ("response.csv"),
    content = function(file) { 
      write_csv(data.frame(Dog= ifelse(input$type==2,1,NA),
                           Cat= ifelse(input$type==1,1,NA),
                           Small= ifelse(input$size=='small',1,NA),
                           Medium= ifelse(input$size=='medium',1,NA),
                           Larg= ifelse(input$size=='size',1,NA)),

                path = file) 
    }
  )

}
```

## Update:

Checkbox Group Input Control description is *Create a group of checkboxes that can be used to toggle multiple choices independently* ,so we can create a `reactiveValues` to hold the selected options and toggle them as one choice "not independently" using `observeEvent`.

```
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)

  # Define UI for survey
  ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Pet Survey"),

    # Sidebar with a selector and checkboxes 
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("type",
                    "Type:",
                    c("Cat" = 1,
                      "Dog" = 2)
        ),

        checkboxGroupInput(inputId="size",
                           label = "Size",
                           choices = list("Small" = "small",
                                          "Medium" = "medium",
                                          "Large" = "large"),
                           selected = NULL)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        HTML("Download data"),
        br(), br(), 
        dataTableOutput('tbl'),
        actionButton('go',"Save"),br(),br(),
        downloadButton("download_data", "Download data")
      )
    ))


  # Define server logic 
  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observe(print(input$size))

    data <- reactiveValues()

    observeEvent(input$go,{

      data$size <- input$size

      data$table <- data.frame(Dog= ifelse(input$type==2,1,NA),
                 Cat= ifelse(input$type==1,1,NA),
                 Small= ifelse(c('small') %in% data$size,1,NA),
                 Medium= ifelse(c('medium') %in% data$size,1,NA),
                 Larg= ifelse(c('large') %in% data$size,1,NA))
    })

    output$tbl <- renderDataTable(data$table)
    # Download file
    output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
      filename = ("response.csv"),
      content = function(file) { 
        write_csv(data$table,path = file) 
      }
    )

  }


  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This seems to work, however if I need to check multiple boxes, the csv output will have multiple lines instead of just one line